# R web scraping/crawling

Tags: xml, r, rcurl, lubridate

I am trying to crawl https://www.nyse.com/bell/calendar.  For some reason when I pull the html it returns to a different html that I can find when I use inspect elemt to look at the html. I used the following functions:

```
SetDir = "~/NYSE/"

setwd(SetDir)

CreateDir = paste(SetDir, "RawData/", sep="")

if("RawData" %in% dir(SetDir)==FALSE){
  dir.create(CreateDir)
}



    url = paste("https://www.nyse.com/bell/calendar", sep="")
    urlname <- paste(CreateDir, ".html", sep="")
    err <- try(download.file(url,destfile = urlname, quiet=FALSE), silent=TRUE)
    if(class(err)=="try-error"){
      Sys.sleep(5)
      try(download.file(url,destfile = urlname, quiet=FALSE), silent=TRUE)
    }
```

I get the following Warning Message after the above commands:

```
Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = urlname, method = "internal", mode = "w",  :
  downloaded length 18598 != reported length 200
```

I have even tried very simple functions using packages such as RCurl:

```
script <- readLines("https://www.nyse.com/bell/calendar")
script <- getURL("https://www.nyse.com/bell/calendar")
```

I do not get an error just the same HTML as I was getting before, which is not the same as the one when inspecting on the website.  For some reason it does not seem to retrieve the html that I am looking for.  When I try other sites, these methods work.  I am slightly lost as to what is going on here, is this specific site protected?

Thank you.

Comment: You can read https://www.intercontinentalexchange.com/terms-of-use, right?

Comment: yes, looks like a no, but why?  Isn't this public information as it is, why would I not be allowed to use this?

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with any site's ToS but I'm also law-abiding (always lawful-neutral in DoD/RPGs, too). They believe they're protecting their digital intellectual property/assets.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Selenium with the R package RSelenium :

```
library(RSelenium)
url <- "https://www.nyse.com/bell/calendar"
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)
html_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
```